# How to Create custom xml file for demo content for custom theme?

Tags: theme-development, menus, content, theme-options

I am created custom Wordpress theme.

Now i need to create functionality for demo content import such as Pages, Posts, Widgets, media and menu.

My question for demo content is possible for above mentioned all things?

How can we set menu using demo content?

also, how can we import widgets?

Answer (score 2):

Use this plugins

https://wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-export-import/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-importer-exporter/

https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/one-click-demo-import/

Read the instructions of the plugins, with their help you can solve your question.

Comment: do you have any better suggestion for customization import/export functionality options for theme. because above your added links already read.